# Help adding 3 more on/off switches so that I can control 4 LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sketch, ethernet-shield

This code is working fine to switch on/off one LED. Can anyone help me add 3 more on/off buttons so that I can control 4 LEDs?

```cpp
#include <String.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE , 0xAD , 0xBE , 0xEF , 0xFE , 0xED
};
byte ip[] = {
  192 , 168 , 2 , 20
};
byte gateway[] = { 
  192 , 168 , 2 , 1
};
byte subnet[] = { 
  255 , 255 , 255, 0
};
EthernetServer server(80);
String richiesta;
int pinLed = 9;

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac,ip,gateway,subnet);
  pinMode(pinLed,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  richiesta = "";
}

void loop() {
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if(client) {
    Serial.println("Tujse na ho payega");
    while(client.connected()) {
      if(client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        richiesta.concat(c);
        if(c == '\n') {
          Serial.print(richiesta);
          if(richiesta.indexOf("Led=1")>0) {
            Serial.println("Pin will be high");
            digitalWrite(pinLed,HIGH);
          } else {
            Serial.println("Pin will be low");
            digitalWrite(pinLed,LOW);
          }
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 ok");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();
          client.println("<head><title> Home Automation</title></head>");
          client.print("<body> <a href='/?Led=1'>ButtonOn </a> <a href='/?Led=0'>Buttonoff </a></body>");
          client.stop();
          richiesta = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just use an array, `int pinMode[4]` and then use loops to access it, you will be able to add as many leds as you want (pins allowing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html you send must be changes to add the buttons:

```
client.print("<body> <a href='/?Led1=1'>Button1On </a> <a href='/?Led1=0'>Button1off </a>");
client.print("<a href='/?Led2=1'>Button2On </a> <a href='/?Led2=0'>Button2off </a>");
client.print("<a href='/?Led3=1'>Button3On </a> <a href='/?Led3=0'>Button3off </a>");
client.print("<a href='/?Led4=1'>Button4On </a> <a href='/?Led4=0'>Button4off </a></body>");
```

Then you need to add some ifs:

```
  if(richiesta.indexOf("Led1=1")>0) {
    Serial.println("Pin1 will be high");
    digitalWrite(pin1Led,HIGH);
  } else if(richiesta.indexOf("Led1=0")>0){
    Serial.println("Pin1 will be low");
    digitalWrite(pin1Led,LOW);
  }
  if(richiesta.indexOf("Led2=1")>0) {
    Serial.println("Pin2 will be high");
    digitalWrite(pin2Led,HIGH);
  } else if(richiesta.indexOf("Led2=0")>0){
    Serial.println("Pin2 will be low");
    digitalWrite(pin2Led,LOW);
  }
  //etc.
```

you can use arrays and loops to avoid the repeated code each time.

Comment: I'm not saying that this solution is wrong, it isn't, but using loops and case statements would make this solution much better.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays, one for switches, one for leds. I don't see the code for leds in your code.

Note that you need 8 pins (4 for switches, 4 for leds).

Initialize them, e.g.

int switchPins[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

Same for leds

```
int ledPins[] = {6, 7, 8, 9};
```

To access them, use a for loop:

```
for (int iLed = 0; iLed < 4; i++)
{
   digitalWrite(ledPins[iLed], HIGH);
}
```

Because 4 might be used a lot, consider them making const or define:

```
#define NR_OF_LEDS 4

for (int iLed = 0; iLed < NR_OF_LEDS; i++)
{
   digitalWrite(ledPins[iLed], HIGH);
}
```

or use the length of the array

```
for (int iLed = 0; iLed < sizeof(ledPins) / sizeof(int); i++)
{
   digitalWrite(ledPins[iLed], HIGH);
}
```

Comment: I think the switches are on the web page.

Comment: Than add 3 more switches on the web page.